# Magento Product Import Error - Error's out after line 43

Tags: error, import, products, dataflow

I have been trying to import a set of products now for the last 3 days and I still cannot get it to work.

I am using the Dataflow - Profiles

I have a document with 180 lines.

I can import the first 42 succesffully without any issues at all. But on the 43rd it just throws up Row error-0- [image]

Things I have tried:

- Opened the document in Notepad to see if there are any hidden , encase its skipping a row.
- Saved the document as a .csv
- Saved the document as a UTF-8
- Removed all column headers leaving the bear essentials.
- Tried changing to another lot of products that I need to import.

Comment: Have you tried to split your csv into two and import the first 42 ?

Comment: Sometimes, server starts to reject requests from same IP with high frequency. It generally happens on shared hosting environment. You can try having a pause somewhere in the script to see if that's the case.

Comment: @brentwpeterson  Yes I have, I imported the rest and this time it only imported upto line 23. Then I deleted that and imported the rest and it did the next 15....

Answer (score -1):

Install Magmi , this extension is a lot better for uploading products into magento. It resolves errors in your csv files as well.

Here's more about magmi : http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

I would recommend that for a bulk upload.